# Magento 2 : Module to send Delivery Notification

Tags: magento2, module, delivery

Anyone know a Module for `Magento 2.1`

Which will able to send **Delivery Notifications** of items? 
( *For UPS or FedEx* )

> Ex: 
>   Item in Transisit Notification.
>   Item Arrived to Destination Country Notification. 
>   Item Delivered Notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of delivery extensions out there for magetno2 which are  paid versions

Some of them are mentioned below

> 1. https://firebearstudio.com/blog/fedex-shipping-manager-magento-2-extension.html
>
>    - Fedex
> 2. https://marketplace.magento.com/pme-shipping-deliverydate.html?source=pepperjam&publisherId=173133&clickId=3017191361
> 3. https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-order-delivery-date.html?source=pepperjam&publisherId=173133&clickId=3017191846
> 4. https://marketplace.magento.com/pme-shipping-deliverydate.html?source=pepperjam&publisherId=173133&clickId=3017191885
> 5. https://marketplace.magento.com/xtento-deliverydate.html?source=pepperjam&publisherId=173133&clickId=3017191912
> 6. https://www.mageworx.com/delivery-date-magento-2.html